# Jave - paintComponent random only once

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm just started to learn Java.

I'm trying to build a program that draw in the JPanel random shapes once, and it doesn't change' even in resizing.
If the user wants (by a Dialog box) the shapes will repaint all over again.

How can I do that?

The number of shapes or they color is not fixed and can be change.

Thanks!

Comment: For us to help you, you must post your code

Comment: I strongly second @ControlAltDel's advise above. It's very hard to guess what you're doing wrong or how to help you without code.

Comment: I wish I had something..I cant figure out how to even start!

Comment: There so many examples for drawing with Swing to be found on this site with simple searching. Please have a look.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, however, we could address the second part of the question... the part about drawing only once

Answer (score 2):

> a program that draw in the JPanel random shapes once, and it doesn't change'

In the constructor of your class you need to generate the random shapes.

In the `paintComponent()` method you then just paint the shapes.

In other words don't generate any random code in a painting method because you can't control when the painting method is invoked.